# Extract maximum value with object name in Access using SQL - handle identical values

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have a table containing information on customers and products in an Access database:

```
custID product price
--------------------
1   objectA   12,5
1   objectB   54,51
1   objectC   14,85
2   objectE  188,84
2   objectC   14,85
2   objectD  188,84
```

From that table I would like to get the most expensive product a customer bought by SQL. I tried this:

```
SELECT a.custID, a.product, max(a.price)
FROM orders AS a INNER JOIN orders AS b ON (a.custID=b.custID) AND (a.price<=b.price)
GROUP BY a.product, a.custID
HAVING count(*)<2;
```

The result is

```
1   objectB  54,51
```

It works all right for all cases where the maximum price occurs only once, but fails when two products have the same (maximum) price. How to make sure to get a result for each customer? (I don't care wether it will by objectD or objectE for customer 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.custID, MAX(a.product), MAX(a.price)
FROM orders AS a 
WHERE a.price = (select MAX(b.price) from orders b where a.custID=b.custID)
GROUP by a.custID
```

Just a side note:
If you have a more advanced SQL server that supports windowing functions, like SQL Server 2008 you can instead write

```
SELECT custID, product, price FROM (
    SELECT custID, product, price,  ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER (partition by custid order by price desc) AS rowNo
    FROM orders 
) AS a
WHERE a.rowNo = 1
```

Comment: BTW sql is a generic tag and does not refer to SQL Server.